# Ktor integration with Azure Application Insight, Key Vault & Blob storage

Tags: azure, kotlin, ktor

I am new to Kotlin & Ktor framework, mainly having experience on Java & Spring Boot frameworks. We are in the process of migrating our Spring boot microservice application into Ktor based microservices. As a cloud partner we are using Azure along with different integrations from Spring to Azure application insight, Key Value & Blob Storage. So while migrating from Spring Boot to Ktor, we are looking for similar plugins available in Ktor for the same Azure integration. Does any one have any idea how to get this integrations done or any plugin already available in the ktor framework?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We can integrate Spring Boot with Azure application insight by adding following dependencies on the pom.xml : 
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
 <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
 <artifactId>applicationinsights-web-auto</artifactId>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
 <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
 </dependency>
While doing the same integration from ktor is there any dependencies available?

Comment: I am not able to find any documentation related to ktor to integrate my application with Azure application insight, keeping all the password in Azure key vault and try to access it using ktor, and also want to use the library provided by azure for azure storage.Is this integration possible?